# Python - how to prevent a button from being pressed like flooding? Deactivating the button action for a while to stop brute force

Tags: python, linux, user-interface, gtk, pygtk

I have three buttons. Each buttons on click sends a command to port 58888 which has some jobs, once the job is done, basically that specific button should be available after 5 minutes to press again.

Any idea how can i block the button? So that someone cant generate flooding on that button for a while??

```
  button = gtk.Button("a")
  button.connect("clicked" , self.on_the_fly("a") , None)
  bbox.add(button)

  button = gtk.Button("v")
  button.connect("clicked" , self.on_the_fly("v") , None)
  bbox.add(button)

  button = gtk.Button("b")
  button.connect("clicked" , self.on_the_fly("b") , None)
  bbox.add(button)
```

Method used by button:

```
  def on_the_fly(self, input):

    logging.debug(  'Clicked at x={0}, y={0}' )

    try:

      if self.myname.startswith("enduser"):
        logging.debug("reconnect")

      else:

        if input.startswith("a"):

          command = "r0x01"
          client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
          client_socket.connect(("localhost", 58888))
          client_socket.send(command)
          client_socket.close()

        elif input.startswith("v"):

          command = "r0x02"
          client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
          client_socket.connect(("localhost", 58888))
          client_socket.send(command)
          client_socket.close()

        elif input.startswith("both"):

          command = "r0x03"
          client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
          client_socket.connect(("localhost", 58888))
          client_socket.send(command)
          client_socket.close()

        else:

          print "nothing"

        subprocess.Popen(["/var/tmp/runme.sh"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    except Exception, err:
      logging.debug(  err )
      pass
```

Comment: @user1775603: I doubt he wants to freeze up the entire app for 5 minutes…

Comment: The code you've given doesn't actually do what you claim. It calls `self.on_the_fly("a")`, `self.on_the_fly("v")`, and `self.on_the_fly("b")` immediately on startup, and logs an exception about None not being callable whenever you click the buttons.

Comment: I do not want it freeze, i have multi tasking GUI button interface, which externally with thread or process does the tasks. But the buttons on press should not allow for minimum 5 minutes to avoid duplicate tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to "insensitivize" the button (Gtk-speak for "deactivate", "disable", or "grey out"), then set up a timer than re-sensitivizes it 5 minutes later.

This means you want to pass the button itself, not just the letter, to the command function.

It's a bit harder to show you how to do this than it should be, because your command functions are already wrong. You're *calling* `self.on_the_fly` in each `connect` call, and connecting the button to the return value (`None`). So, your program calls `on_the_fly` three times at startup, then logs an exception about `None` not being callable whenever you click a button. What you wanted is one of the following:

```
button.connect("clicked", self.on_the_fly, "a")

button.connect("clicked", lambda: self.on_the_fly("a"), None)
```

So, the way you pass the button widget as well is either:

```
button.connect("clicked", self.on_the_fly, ("a", button))

button.connect("clicked", lambda: self.on_the_fly("a", button), None)
```

Then, you change the `on_the_fly` method like this:

```
def on_the_fly(self, input, widget):
    logging.debug(  'Clicked at x={0}, y={0}' )
    widget.set_sensitive(False)
    gtk.timeout_add_seconds(5*60, widget.set_sensitive, True)
    # rest of function
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'timeout_add_seconds'
` - Thank you. Python 2.7.3 i get this. i have only `.timeout_add(second, func)`

Comment: @YumYumYum: It doesn't matter which Python version you have; it matters which Gtk+ bindings you're using (PyGtk/Gobject/whatever) and which version, and possibly which Gtk+ version. You might want to try calling it on `glib` or `gobject` or `gobj` if you have such modules. Meanwhile, I don't know of any version where `timeout_add` takes `(seconds, func)`; they all take `(milliseconds, func, ...)`. If so, unless you want this to disable the button for 0.3 seconds, you need to add a `*1000` in there. (But please read the docs and/or say what you're using, instead of going by my random guess.)

Comment: never use timeout_add() when the milliseconds don't matter, use timeout_add_seconds(): not only is it easier, it's also more power efficient.